# How can I get a blurred background with a kit lens?

Tags: blur, kit-lens, background, nikon-d3300

How can I take a image with blur background? I am a new photographer but its no my profession, its my passion. If someone know about this then tell me.

Comment: Use one point for autofocus and use apperture priority or full manual and set the smaller (wide open) apperture.

Comment: @Crowley [Please don't post answers as comments](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4655/short-answers-as-comments-please-resist-the-urge).

Answer (score 0):

The sample way to do it (to archive maximum out of focus of background)

1. Open the aperture as much as possible
2. Set zoom lens to maximum focal length
3. Make object as close as possible to the camera and background as far
   away as possible from the camera